# Debian APT - some questions

Tags: package, debian, apt

1. How can I check which packages are currently installed?
2. How can I find all packages that are not installed?
3. Is possible to uninstall package and all files of that package (config, temporaries, etc.)?

I'm using Debian Squeeze 6.0.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. dpkg -l
2. well there will be A LOT of NOT installed packages.. why would you want to do that? btw, the command `apt-cache pkgnames` will provide you the list of ALL available packages in the repository added in your sources.list configuration
3. apt-get remove  will remove the installed package, but you'll normally keep the configurations, which is the desired behaviour usually.

further info: http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/linux/dpkg-cheat-sheet.php

Comment: Well, thank you a lot. 2. question I asked cos I just wanted to know.